# Obtain image source and save to database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an image that is populated after searching for it and once it is in the image control i now want to insert it into the database.

This is my code for submitting the selected data into the database. I am getting an error on the line cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", image1)

```
 Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

     Dim d As New Date(2019, 5, 16)
     d = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 365, d)

     Dim currentID As Integer
     Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
     Dim contentType As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
     Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
     Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
     Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CType(fs.Length, Integer))

     'Try

        If txtClockNo.Text <> "" And txtDepartment.Text <> "" And txtName.Text <> "" And txtIDNo.Text <> "" And txtSurname.Text <> "" And txtCostCentre.Text <> "" Then

            Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("##").ToString())

                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MedicalCertificate (Code,EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,DateOfMedical,DateOfUpload,Certificate,UploadType,Photo)  VALUES (@Code,@EmployeeID,@FirstName,@LastName,@DateOfMedical,@DateOfUpload,@Certificate,@UploadType,@Photo);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", con)             

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", txtClockNo.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", txtIDNo.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtName.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtSurname.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfMedical", DateTime.Today())
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfUpload", DateTime.Today())
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Certificate", bytes)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UploadType", contentType)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", image1)

                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    currentID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

                    con.Close()

                End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the variable `image1` declared? To save it to a database, that variable should be a `Byte()` and the database field should be a `VarBinary`

Comment: It is declared in the search function of the form: Protected Sub btnSearchEmployee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs). Dim img() As Byte

                img = tbl.Rows(0)(7)
                image1.Src = "data:image/png;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(img)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: `image1` is a complex object which represents a HTML element in your page. You don't need or want to store all that in your database, you only need the image data itself. Since you appear to have inserted the image as a base64 string, then the data you want to store in the database is that base64 string...you can get that from the `image1.Src` property. Since it's a string representation of the image, your `Photo` field in the database will need to be an `nvarchar`.

Comment: However it's unclear if that's actually the right place to get the data. You also seem to be dealing with an uploaded file...so maybe what you want to place into the database is actually the uploaded file? So the Photo field would be a binary field in the database, and you'd insert `bytes` into it. That _seems_ to make more sense, but like I say you haven't been very clear what the actual process you want to achieve is.

Comment: Thanks so much @ ADyson I appreciate your expert opinion.

Comment: No worries. Did any of it help to solve your problem?

Comment: @ADyson , yes it did thanks. I changed my data type in the database and it helped solve my problem.